# Parsing a stringified array to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, datetime, data-structures

I have a component that throws the following in the backend

```
memberSince: [ '["2022-05-05T08:13:07.551Z","2022-06-01T08:13:07.551Z"]' ]
```

Is there a way to un-stringify the array content like `memberSince[0].parse()` or something

Comment: `JSON.parse(memberSince[0])`

Comment: [Here's the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). (PS. It is the first entry when you search for [javascript parse](https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=javascript+parse).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```js
const data = {memberSince: ['["2022-05-05T08:13:07.551Z","2022-06-01T08:13:07.551Z"]']}

const result = JSON.parse(data.memberSince)

console.log(result)
```